# How can I use NiFi to read/write directly from ADLS without HDInsight

Tags: apache-nifi, azure-data-lake, azure-hdinsight, databricks

We would like to use NiFi to connect with ADLS (using PutHDFS and FetchHDFS) without having to install HDInsight.  Subsequently we want to use Azure DataBricks to run Spark jobs, and hoping that it can be done using NiFi's ExecuteSparkInteractive processor. From all the examples I could find, invariably HDP or HDInsight seem to be required.

Can anyone share the pointers how it can be done without needing HDP or HDInsight?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, ADLS won't work well (or work at all) with `*HDFS` processors available in Apache NiFi. There was a feature request made - [NIFI-4360](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-4360) and a subsequent PR raised for the same - [#2158](https://github.com/apache/nifi/pull/2158) but it was briefly reviewed but now not much progress is there. You can fork that or copy pasta that code-base and hopefully review it.

Comment: Thanks Siva. Exploring StreamSets as well.

Answer (score 0):

I did a test-setup more than a year ago. The PutHDFS processor worked with some additional classpath resources. The following dependencies have been required:

- adls2-oauth2-token-provider-1.0.jar
- azure-data-lake-store-sdk-2.0.4-SNAPSHOT.jar
- hadoop-azure-datalake-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
- jackson-core-2.2.3.jar
- okhttp-2.4.0.jar
- okio-1.4.0.jar

See also the following [Blog](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/71916/connecting-to-azure-data-lake-from-a-nifi-dataflow.html) for more details. You can copy the libs, the core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml from an HDInsight setup to the machine where NiFi is running. You also should set the dfs.adls.home.mountpoint properly, directing to root or a data directory. Be aware that this is not officially supported, so phps. you should also consider Azure Data Factory or StreamSets as an option for Data Ingest.

Comment: Thanks Hauke. Actively considering StreamSets, ADF is not an option as of now.

Answer (score 0):

PutHDFS does not expect a classic hadoop cluster in the first place. It expects core-site.xml only for conventional reasons. As you will see in the below example a minimalist config file to have PutHDFS work with ADLS.

Using NiFi PutHDFS processor to ingress into ADLS is simple. Below steps will lead to the solution

1. Have ADLS Gen1 set up(ADLS has been renamed as ADLS Gen1)
2. Additionally have OAUTH authentication set up for your ADLS account. See [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-azure-datalake/index.html)
3. Create an empty core-site.xml for configuring PuHDFS processor
   Update core-site.xml with the following properties(I am using Client keys mode for auth in this example) 
   `fs.defaultFS = adl://<yourADLname>.azuredatalakestore.net` 
   `fs.adl.oauth2.access.token.provider.type = ClientCredential`
   `fs.adl.oauth2.refresh.url = <Your Azure refresh endpoint>`
   `fs.adl.oauth2.client.id = <Your application id>`
   `fs.adl.oauth2.credential = <Your key>`
4. Update your NiFi PutHDFS processor to refer to the core-site.xml and additional ADLS libraries(hadoop-azure-datalake-3.1.1.jar and azure-data-lake-store-sdk-2.3.1.jar) created in previous step as shown below. 
   [image]
5. Update the upstream processors and test.

Comment: Krishnan, Thanks but this looks like a hack. I would like to wait for an official support for ADLS without any dependency on any Hadoop distribution.